# Failing to parse a String date

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I'm going nuts trying to parse the 2 following dates:

```
Thu, 13 Feb 2014 13:03:50 GMT
13 Feb 2014 13:03:50 GMT
```

I did try the following SimpleDate patterns with no success:

```
"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"
"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
"dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'"
```

Here's my code

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatPattern, Locale.US);
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateString);
```

But I'm always getting ParseException...
Any idea why ?

Comment: Can you paste the full stack trace please?

Comment: The first date pattern works fine for me, the parsed date is `Thu Feb 13 14:03:50 GMT 2014`: [IDEone example](http://ideone.com/egRutz)

Comment: Emulator or real device?

Comment: it fails on a real nexus 5

Comment: @user1026605 Then post the LogCat, otherwise we can't know the exact exception being thrown

Comment: @user1026605 Just tried on my nexus 5, your code works with no `ParseException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what in which pattern you want

but I tried in my way

This code is for `Thu, 13 Feb 2014 13:03:50 GMT` format

```
String DateStr="Thu, 13 Feb 2014 13:03:50 GMT";
SimpleDateFormat sim=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(DateStr); 
System.out.println(sim.format(d));
```

**output**

```
2014/02/13 13:03:50
```

And the following code is for `13 Feb 2014 13:03:50 GMT` format

```
String DateStr="13 Feb 2014 13:03:50 GMT";
    SimpleDateFormat sim=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(DateStr); 
System.out.println(sim.format(d));
```

**output** `2014/02/13 13:03:50`

Comment: Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss").parse(DateStr); fails on android

Comment: Sorry I need to sleep more... I added the locale when copying the code from memory in SO but in my code I forget to use the Locale... so with new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatPattern, Locale.US); it works fine and it was failing with new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormatPattern);
Sorry about that :(

Comment: @user1026605 no need to feel sorry,It happens with beginners.Glad that your problem is solved

Comment: That's exactly why I feel sorry. I'm not really a beginner...

Comment: @user1026605 How many years of experience do you have ?I am having 1 year experience

Answer (score 1):

`EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zz` does not match `13 Feb 2014 13:03:50 GMT` correctly.

Comment: it fails on android...